# See the port addresses and properties of installed devices

Tags: c#, sockets, port

I installed a device on my computer (for example a cardreader). I ran this code but the `ComboBox` was not filled.

Code:

```
using System.Management;
using System.IO.Ports;

foreach (string portname in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(portname);
        }
```

Since this didn't work, how can I see the port addresses and properties of the devices installed on the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetPortNames() function provides a list of the serial port names [see GetPortNames() page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames.aspx) which are not sockets.

Here is [documentation on the SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) which has methods that you can use to determine the properties of a particular serial port including baud rate, etc.  I suspect that the basic outline of what you want is to use the `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` method to generate a list of port names and to then use the `SerialPort (String)` to interogate the properties of the specific port as you iterate through the list of ports provided by `GetPortNames()`.

If it is actually sockets you are interested in, you may want to know a [list of well know TCP and UDP ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) however like the pirate's code these are more like guidelines than actual rules and what is actually on a port may not be what the standard usage documents.  It depends on what software is running and how the software is configured.  I do not know of any way of knowing what service may be using a particular port other than going by the standard list, sending a service specific query to the port, or to use a [utility such as netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) to generate a list.